# How can I put the value with the same key in the same line using R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to turn this:

```
Wood Tabletops  RE170590
        
Wood Tabletops  RE170590    
    
Wood Tabletops  RE170590
        
Wood Tabletops  RE170590    
    
Wood Tabletops  RE170590    
    
Wood Tabletops  RE170590

Watertap    RE170584
    
Water Heater    RE170584
```

Into this:

```
Wood Tabletops, Wood Tabletops, Wood Tabletops, Wood Tabletops, Wood Tabletops

Watertap, Water Heater
```

Comment: You need explain better the what/how/why of what you want to do?

Comment: I want to put the value with the same RE number in the same line use R.

I don't know what to search for on Google. I - digital marketing background so.. any links and suggestion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already imported the table from Google spreadsheets into `R` as a dataframe called `df`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df2 <- df[, paste(pr, collapse = ", "), by = pr_id]
```

This uses `data.table` to group by id number and then paste the product names. Other packages and methods could alse be used.

```
# Example
df2[pr_id == "RE170593"]
      pr_id                                                                  V1
1: RE170593 Walnut Table tops, Modification of metal table stands reduce height
```

---

Assuming you haven't imported the spreadsheet yet, then you could use something like the following to get it straight from Google sheets, using the `googlesheets` package
:

```
library(googlesheets)
url <- paste0("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/", 
              "13RSMGJMWx1mUcIzzj2gVn2N8GHTDTp7aDQTVGMVz0Zw")
gs_obj <- gs_url(url)
df <- setDT(gs_read(gs_obj))
df <- df[complete.cases(df)]
names(df) <- c("pr", "pr_id")
```

Comment: I don't understand much about this, but I'll follow your instruction btw what's pr_id?

Comment: Dividing your data into two columns... where `RE170590`... is `pr_id`

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
tab <- tribble(
  ~ type, ~id,
  "Wood.Tabletops" ,"RE170590",
  "Wood Tabletops", "RE170590",
  "Wood Tabletops", "RE170590",
  "Wood Tabletops", "RE170590",
  "Wood Tabletops", "RE170590",
  "Wood Tabletops", "RE170590",
  "Watertap", "RE170584",
  "Water Heater", "RE170584"
  )
```

you could reshape as a data.frame with na value

```r
tab %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  spread(rowid, type)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 9
#>   id       `1`            `2`     `3`     `4`    `5`    `6`    `7`   `8`  
#> * <chr>    <chr>          <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
#> 1 RE170584 <NA>           <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   Wate~ Wate~
#> 2 RE170590 Wood.Tabletops Wood T~ Wood T~ Wood ~ Wood ~ Wood ~ <NA>  <NA>
```

You can also use list-column

```r
tab %>%
  nest(-id) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, pull, type)) %>%
  str()
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ id  : chr  "RE170590" "RE170584"
#>  $ data:List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr  "Wood.Tabletops" "Wood Tabletops" "Wood Tabletops" "Wood Tabletops" ...
#>   ..$ : chr  "Watertap" "Water Heater"
```

or play with some list format

```r
tab %>%
  transpose() %>%
  rlist::list.group(id) %>%
  modify_depth(2, "type") %>%
  map(flatten_chr)
#> $RE170584
#> [1] "Watertap"     "Water Heater"
#> 
#> $RE170590
#> [1] "Wood.Tabletops" "Wood Tabletops" "Wood Tabletops" "Wood Tabletops"
#> [5] "Wood Tabletops" "Wood Tabletops"
```

Created on 2018-01-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

final_val <- df %>%
  group_by(V2) %>%
  summarise(val=paste(V1, collapse=", "))
final_val$val
```

Output is:

```
[1] "                 Watertap,                  Water Heater"                                                                                                          
[2] "Wood Tabletops, Wood Tabletops,                  Wood Tabletops,                  Wood Tabletops,                  Wood Tabletops,                  Wood Tabletops"
```

```
#sample data
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c("Wood Tabletops", "Wood Tabletops", "                 Wood Tabletops", 
"                 Wood Tabletops", "                 Wood Tabletops", 
"                 Wood Tabletops", "                 Watertap", 
"                 Water Heater"), V2 = c(" RE170590", " RE170590", 
" RE170590", " RE170590", " RE170590", " RE170590", " RE170584", 
" RE170584")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```